# Using forEach method in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is forEach method designed to work for only array in javascript?Can anyone share idea or an example on what major task can be completed with forEach() method or is it useful for only getting element value and index?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach - would be the best start for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

It is designed to work on arrays, but can operate on any array-like object (although you still have to access it from somewhere where it exists).

For example, on a NodeList:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    document.getElementsByTagName('div'), 
    function (divElement) { console.log(divElement); }
);
```

Comment: Try `"abc".forEach(function(v){console.log(v)})`. You'd have to use apply or call.

Comment: @dystroy — Yes, you have to use apply or call. That doesn't mean you can't use it.

Comment: @Quentin I agree (and I didn't downvote). I simply think this should be clearer.

Comment: @Quentin i agree too, with the use of call and apply it works but is it only for Nodelist?

Comment: @Maizere - No, _any_ array-like object, e.g., it would work on this object: `{"0":10,"1":20,"length":2}`.

Comment: @nnnnnn is the use of call and apply compulsory for arry-like objects

Comment: @Maizere — No, but you have to do something to set `this` (inside the `forEach` function) to be the array-like object you want to operate on.

Comment: @Quentin that will be too complicated

Comment: @Quentin since it is designed invoke func for the element of an array how can it invoke function for the object with string key

Comment: @Maizere — It can't. It operates on array-like objects.

Comment: @nnnnnn forEach() method doesn't work for the object u mentioned

Answer (score 1):

It is an Array function. See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

You *can* use it on any array-like object but it's not very convenient because you have to use `apply` or `call`. For example :

```
[].forEach.call("abc",function(v){console.log(v)})
```

To iterate over objects keys, you should use [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) :

```
for (key in object) {
    var value = object[key];
}
```

Note that jQuery's compatibility function [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) enables the same iteration function for both arrays and non array objects but you generally know if you're dealing with an array (or you should) so I'd use it only for compatibility with old browsers.

Comment: Just for good reading as well! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Answer (score -1):

The forEach method in JavaScript allows you to traverse an array and apply a particular action to each of its elements through a function. Let's see an example:

array.forEach(function(elementoActual, indice, array))

elmentoActual: es el valor del elemento actual del array.
índice: es el índice del elemento actual del array (opcional).
array: es el array que se está recorriendo (opcional).

For more information I leave the following article
https://4geeks.com/es/how-to/metodo-foreach-javascript

Comment: Did you mean to post to [ES.SO]?

Comment: Code formatting